# Spread and Gather table return duplicated rows with NA values

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I have a table with categories and sub categories encoded in this format of columns name:

> Date| Admissions__0 |Attendance__0 |Tri_1__0|Tri_2__0|...
>   Tri_1__1|Tri_2__1|...|

and I would like to change it to this format of columns **using spread and gather function of tidyverse:**

> Date| Country code| Admissions| Attendance| Tri_1|Tri_2|...

I tried a solution posted but the outcome actually return multiple rows with NA rather than a single row.

My code used:

```r
temp <- data %>% gather(key="columns",value ="dt",-Date) 

temp <- temp %>% mutate(category = gsub(".*__","",columns)) %>% mutate(columns = gsub("__\\d","",columns))

temp %>%  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% spread(key="columns",value="dt")
```

And my results is:

```
Date        country_code   row admissions attendance Tri_1 Tri_2 Tri_3 Tri_4 Tri_5
   <chr>       <chr>        <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 01-APR-2014 0              275 NA         209        NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 2 01-APR-2014 0              640 84         NA         NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 3 01-APR-2014 0             1005 NA         NA         5     NA    NA    NA    NA   
 4 01-APR-2014 0             1370 NA         NA         NA    33    NA    NA    NA   
 5 01-APR-2014 0             1735 NA         NA         NA    NA    62    NA    NA   
 6 01-APR-2014 0             2100 NA         NA         NA    NA    NA    80    NA   
 7 01-APR-2014 0             2465 NA         NA         NA    NA    NA    NA    29   
 8 01-APR-2014 1             2830 NA         138        NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 9 01-APR-2014 1             3195 66         NA         NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
10 01-APR-2014 1             3560 NA         NA         N/A   NA    NA    NA    NA
```

My expected results:

```
Date        country_code   row admissions attendance Tri_1 Tri_2 Tri_3 Tri_4 Tri_5
   <chr>       <chr>        <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 01-APR-2014 0              275 84         209        5    33    62    80    29   
 8 01-APR-2014 1             2830 66         138        66   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible input data

Comment: I think you need `temp %>% group_by(Date, country_code) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%spread(key="columns",value="dt") ` (not tested as there was no input example)

Comment: @akrun thank you. https://data.gov.au/dataset/ds-dga-6bfec5ea-207e-4d67-8965-c7e72290844b/distribution/dist-dga-33d84954-b13a-4f4e-afb9-6468e287fa3c/details?q= here is my data set that I am working on. I tried your suggestion but it still return the same results as before.

Comment: I tried downloading the data.  I am not getting the same column names as yours.

Comment: @akrun, I editted my columns to the initial columns of the data set, can you have a check for me? thank you in advance!

Comment: @akrun here is the csv file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wKutidGfGdzOZ65d4lUqb88s1k54ayBk thank you

Comment: Not clear whether you need to remove the NA and coalesce together. In that case `data %>% gather(key = "columns", val = "dt",  -Date,  na.rm = TRUE) %>% mutate(category = gsub(".*__","",columns)) %>% mutate(columns = gsub("__\\d","",columns)) %>% group_by(Date, dt, columns, category) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% spread(columns, dt) %>% select(-V1) %>% summarise_at(vars(Admissions:Tri_5),list(~ coalesce(!!! .)))`

Comment: and to further remove all NA rows `%>% filter_at(vars(Admissions:Tri_5), all_vars(!is.na(.)))`

Comment: @akrun problem solved! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a `summarise_at` `coalesce` to remove the `NA` elements after the `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  gather(key = "columns", val = "dt", -Date, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(category = gsub(".*__","",columns)) %>%
  mutate(columns = gsub("__\\d","",columns)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, dt, columns, category) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  spread(columns, dt) %>% 
  select(-V1) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Admissions:Tri_5),list(~ coalesce(!!! .))) # %>%
  # filter if needed
  #filter_at(vars(Admissions:Tri_5), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```